# batch_ Loop line in a file and check if a line begin with "#"

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

hi mate i have to a script .bat for windows shell.
i have this file:

```
line
line
#line
line
#line
```

I want to read the file line by line, and if the line begin with "#" i don't do anything else i do some elaboration. how can do this ? I post the pseudo-code

```
while (s=readline()!=null)
  {

  if(s.charat(0)!='#')
     do some elaboration
   }
```

Comment: By batch file do you mean MS-DOS, or something else?

Comment: i want to do a file .bat and use it in dos

Comment: Do a search on Google for the DOS `For` command - that should get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your pseudo code, is this what you want?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do (
    set line=%%i
    if !line:~0,1! equ # (
        ::Your code here:
    )
)
```

Note, you need to replace `file.txt` with the file you want to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: first way - findstr
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (yourfile.txt) DO (
 ECHO %%i|FINDSTR /b "#" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO non-#  : %%i) ELSE (ECHO #START : %%i)
)
ECHO ====== first way ===========
ENDLOCAL
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
:: second way - substring with delayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (yourfile.txt) DO (
 SET line=%%i
 if "!line:~0,1!"=="#" (ECHO #START : %%i) ELSE (ECHO non-#  : %%i)
)
ECHO ====== second way ===========
ENDLOCAL
SETLOCAL
:: third way -without delayedexpansion substringing and flagging in subroutine
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (yourfile.txt) DO (
 SET line=%%i
 CALL :test
 IF DEFINED line (ECHO non-#  : %%i) ELSE (ECHO #START : %%i)
)
ECHO ====== third way ===========
ENDLOCAL

GOTO :eof

:test
IF "%line:~0,1%"=="#" SET "line="
GOTO :eof
```

Three ways here - depends on further details. Note that the third way uses the characteristic that `IF DEFINED` or `IF ERRORLEVEL` works on the RUN-TIME value of the variable, not the parse-time value

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest way to solve this problem:

```
for /F "eol=# delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
   echo Line that not start with #: %%a
)
```